# How to resolve 0xc000007b error opening Adobe After Effects?

Tags: windows-8, adobe-after-effects

I have installed Adobe CS6 on Windows 8 and get the error "0xc000007b" every time I open open Adobe After Effects. All other Adobe software, including Photoshop and Premiere Pro, work perfectly. I have looked online extensively but have not found any solutions.

What can I try/do to resolve this error?

- OS: Windows 8 (64 bit)
- CPU: Intel Core i3-3110M 2,40GHz
- RAM: 6GB DD3
- FX: AMD Radeon HD 7670M

When I open Adobe After Effects CS6 with Dependency Walker, this message appears:

> Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
>
> Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
>
> Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module."

What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: why do you no comment my reply? The tool should tell you which dll is it. Look for the red icon in the module list.

Comment: @magicandre1981 looks like he edited his question to include t what happend when he ran dependency walker

Comment: @barlop he did not post which DLL is highlighted. And it is 6 Months ago, so I doubt he'll ever reply here again.

Answer (score 2):

This error means, that the program tries to load a DLL with the wrong CPU architecture (32/64Bit).

```
C:\Users\André>err 0xc000007b
# for hex 0xc000007b / decimal -1073741701
  STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT                                    ntstatus.h
# {Bad Image}
# %hs is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains
# an error. Try installing the program again using the
# original installation media or contact your system
# administrator or the software vendor for support.
```

Use [Depends.exe](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/06/25/analyze-application-failures-the-easier-way-with-dependency-walker.aspx) to analyze the Adobe After Effects start and look which DLL is causing it.

Use the Profiling feature (<kbd>F7</kbd>)

[image]

click ok to start the profiling:

[image]

After the error occured you should see the failing DLL in red:

[image]

Comment: err.exe mentioned here http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2012/10/06/tool-trying-to-figure-out-what-error-code-0x8007005-and-other-0x0000000-codes-mean.aspx  Did you get it from the 2003 resource kit? or something more recent - what?

Comment: I got the err.exe from the Windows 7 SDK.